# Header token authorization not working for get request in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, header, jwt

I'm working on a project where i need to get the list of users from a restful server. However, My code isn't working as I'm not getting the intended result. The rest server uses a JWT token which means i need to be authorized before i can make a request. Please how do i do this in xamarin forms.
below is my code:

````
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                "Bearer", accessToken);

            var json = await client.GetStringAsync(ConstantsValue.BaseAddress + "Users");

            var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AddedUsers>>(json);

            return users;
        }```
````

Comment: "I'm not getting the intended result" - what are you getting?  Is it an authorization failure or something else?

Comment: do you mean your authorization token was not correctly added to the request header?

Comment: I'm not getting any result. I'm passing it into a cardview that is meant to show the list of users but on click of the page navigation, its always empty

Comment: Can you set some breakpoints in your method and check what is the return value especially in line ```var json = await client.GetStringAsync(ConstantsValue.BaseAddress + "Users");```

Comment: I'm gettign a null

Comment: When you hit this breakpoint, check your ```client``` variable and all its properties(e.g. does it have authorization headers). 
Also, check ```ConstantsValue.BaseAddress``` and verify if the route is correct(check if there is forward slash, try adding "users" instead of "Users" as the endpoint etc).

Comment: the client variable isn't getting any header authorization. I try the forward slash too and it's not working. Is there a way i can catch and save the token upon login? maybe that might help?